# How to crop tilt image in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, aforge, omr

I have tilt image capture by mobile. I want to cut section/portion of image in between two rectangles of both sides to find out circles in between them. I have all 4 co-ordinates of middle section like (x0,y0),(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3).

My Image is looks like,
[image]

But crop function I have something like

```
public static Bitmap CropImage(int x, int y, int width, int height, Bitmap bitmap)
{

    Bitmap croppedImage;
    var originalImage = bitmap;
    {
        Rectangle crop = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        croppedImage = originalImage.Clone(crop, originalImage.PixelFormat);

    } // Here we release the original resource - bitmap in memory and file on disk.

    return croppedImage;
}
```

But above function cuts portion as rectangle as show in 1st and 2nd red color box.
I am looking for code to cut portion shown in 3rd red rectangle. I had search for code and find out below code

```
List<IntPoint> corners = new List<IntPoint>();

corners.Add(new IntPoint(x0, y0));
corners.Add(new IntPoint(x3, y3));
corners.Add(new IntPoint(x1 + 30, y1 + 20));
corners.Add(new IntPoint(x2 + 30, y2 + 0));
AForge.Imaging.Filters.QuadrilateralTransformation filter = new AForge.Imaging.Filters.QuadrilateralTransformation(corners, WidthOfCut, HeightOfCut);
Bitmap newImage = filter.Apply(mainOuterWindow);
```

of AForge.Imaging. library but it will cut potion like below

[image]

which disturb shape of circle and make it ellipse which causes issue for other calculation.
please let me know how to crop image using 4 points.
Or is there is any way to correct the tilt of image by passing correction angle?

Comment: Is it okay to just the extract circles only, or you really want the pixel distortion fix?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the quadrilateral includes angled sides, the resulting transformation actually looks pretty good.

Using this image:

[image]

Transformed by this code:

```
        var i = Image.FromFile("pic.png");

        List<IntPoint> corners = new List<IntPoint>();
        corners.Add(new IntPoint(63, 183));
        corners.Add(new IntPoint(863, 151));
        corners.Add(new IntPoint(869, 182));
        corners.Add(new IntPoint(65, 211));
        QuadrilateralTransformation filter = new QuadrilateralTransformation(corners, 869 - 63, 211 - 183);
        var i2 = filter.Apply(i);

        i2.Save("pic2.png");
```

Results in this image:

[image]

I think that's exactly what you are looking for.

The trick was making sure the quadrilateral transform uses angled sides to avoid the skew.  My points look roughly like this:

[image]

Comment: Better if you use a distance formula and average for width and height, it will be more precise.

Comment: Hi TheSoftwareJedi, thank you so much, it works for me.